# MS Access/VBA used to open an ArcGIS map document: Map fails to connect to database

Tags: arcgis-10.3, windows, vba, ms-access, hyperlink

I have an MS Access front-end that can be used to **open ArcGIS map documents (.mxds)**.

It has a macro that runs an OpenRoadMap() function:

[image]

```
 Function OpenRoadMap()
     CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("{your path here}\ROAD.mxd")  
 End Function
```

**Problem:**

The .mxd connects to the database just fine when I open it manually.

However, when I open the map using the VBA script, the map is **unusable** because it is unable to connect to the database:

[image]

[image]

**Why is the VBA-opened .mxd unable to connect to the database?**

- Windows 7 Enterprise - Service Pack 1
- Microsoft Access 2010
- ArcGIS 10.3.1
- Oracle 12c

Comment: A useful, but unrelated tip: To open vba code from a RunCode macro, the vba must be a **function**, not a procedure. However, it's not necessary to actually pass the function a variable (you can treat it as if it were a procedure). https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244981/5576771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be several different ways to open files with VBA.

When the file is opened using [this alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39903527/5576771), the map is able to **connect to the database successfully**:

```
Function OpenRoadMap()
    Shell "explorer.exe {your path here}\ROAD.mxd"
End Function
```

It seems to be using Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) to open the file. I guess going indirectly through Windows Explorer is is somehow avoiding the database connections being disabled.

I couldn't say why this technique works over the other one. Maybe some VBA libraries have different security settings than others?